# vscode open local file when url links to repo

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode recognizes urls and links in most contexts and let the user "Follow link" opening it in browser or opening a file when it recognizes it as a file url
there's as edge use case in my opinion, though:
when an url points to a current repository resource, it would be quite handy to have the choice to open it as local file instead of in browser
Contexts eligible for this feature could be:

- comments in code
- issue/pr views via vscode-extensions for github/gitlab

any idea to achieve this feature by an extension, a config, or a script ?

Comment: write an extension with a `DocumentLinkProvider`